# Is there a better way to test for null in Dart constructor

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm constructing an object using the following constructor:

```
 class A {
   int col;
   int row;

   A.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> data)
       : col = data['col'],
         row = data['row'];
 }

 class B {
   A aObj;
   int objType;
   int count;

   B.fromMap(Map<dynamic, dynamic> data)
       : objType = data['objType'],
         count = data['count'],
         aObj = A.fromMap(data['A']);
 }
```

The problem is that if the map I'm passing in doesn't have a mapping for aObj, it crashes. I have tried moving the assignment into the curly brackets and testing for null:

```
 if(data['A'] != null) {
    aObj = A.fromMap(data['A']);
 }
```

This works. But I'd like to test as part of the short cut constructor like in the other data members.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about a ternary operator?

```
aObj = data['A'] ? A.fromMap(data['A']) : null;
```

Comment: I like this idea better because it doesn't crate empty/null objects. The problem is that when I try it, I get the following error: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of 'bool'. I get a similar error when using this technique to read in an array of strings/ints. Any ideas?

Comment: The best thing I've been able to figure out is: aObj = data['A'] != null ? A.fromMap(data['A']) : null:    This isn't really all that different than what I started with but it can be put on a single line.

Answer (score 5):

I think how you can prevent crashes in a neat way is this way:

```
aObj = A.fromMap(data['A'] ?? Map())
```

This will return an **empty** `Map` to your *custom `A.fromMap` constructor* when `data['A']` is `null`, which will result in `col` and `row` being `null` afterwards (if `data['A']` is `null`) because the fields do not exist in the `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

With NNBD introduced in Dart 2.8, you can use:

```dart
class Foo {
  final int value;

  // 0 is the default value in case the expression data['key'] returns null
  Foo.fromNonNullable(Map data) : value = data['key'] ?? 0;

  // 0 is the default value in case `data` is `null`
  Foo.fromNullable(Map? data) : value = data?['key'] ?? 0;
}
```